# Image comparison using python open cv (ORB)

Tags: python, opencv

My requirement is to match the image and should show the feature is present or not.
These are the 2 images i am using,

I used the below code to match the features of the 2 images but its not giving correct matching, So do you have any option for matching or any other idea or do I need to change the coding given below.

```
`enter code here`
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cv2.__version__
img1 = cv2.imread('D:/Notsaved/naiduv/Images/img3.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('D:/Notsaved/naiduv/Images/img1.png')

#cv2.imshow('img',img1)
#sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
#kp = sift.detect(img1,None)
#img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp,img)
#cv2.imwrite('sift_keypoints.jpg',img)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllwindows()
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
kp1,des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2,des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
for d in des2:
    print(d)
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
#matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,matches[:1],None, flags=2)
plt.imshow(img3)
plt.show()


   https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8ljO.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSuer.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BDlK.png
```

Comment: What do you mean with " match the image"? have you tried [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)? or is it a totally different thing? xD

Comment: I have tried that but its not working properly. My requirement is I have the 2 images contain a sticker 24v should be detected. If i have 12v sticker it should say not ok